# How to link the device ID to the right contact in SFMC and be able to trigger personalized push notifications / MobilePush?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, mobilepush

Our client wants to use MobilePush to trigger personalized push notifications in real time to their contacts.
His SFMC org will be connected with Salesforce CRM (so the Contact ID on the org would be the SF Contact ID).

His developers will have to integrate Mobile Push SDK in his mobile app.

In MobilePush by default, a device ID is generated for each identified device.
How can we automatically tie the device ID to the right Contact and the right Contact ID ? If this step is not done, I guess it won't be possible to target and personalize push notifications, and create cross channel journeys.
Is there any warnings or points of attention regarding this set up ?

How about contacts that don't have any Contact ID and that may come from other sources than the CRM, how can they be managed in order to get personalized push notifications ?

Can you also confirm that push optin is directly managed inside the application ?

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of questions in there :)

The Marketing Cloud MobilePush SDK will handle device/contact registration for the consumer within the customer's application automatically.

The Device ID is unique within our system and will be tied to the device/contact registration.

You would use `Contact Key` as the unifying key to associate the MobilePush Contact across other clouds.

The SDK can set `Attributes` and/or create `Tags` which can be used for personalization and audience segmentation.

A "best practices" example of most features/functions can be see in the [Learning App](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/tree/master/app).

Comment: have you done this with Salesforce connected accounts? Did you use Salesforce ID as Contact Key?

Comment: Not specifically, no, but I know that we have customers who have.  You might reach out to a success/solutions architect through your account executive for further guidance.

Comment: @BillMote Does this work also existing push subscribers (who already have the app downloaded on their device) ? That is if we use Marketing Cloud MobilePush SDK will it tie the Device ID to Contact Key and send this data to marketing cloud even for theses existing push subscribers.

Comment: Device ID and Contact Key are both part of the device registration.  If you integrate the SDK and set a Contact Key then yes @Harikrishnanmk.